# xpath getting first node query

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm scanning a webpage for images and I only want the first image it finds.

Here's my `xpath`:

`$image = '//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="entry"]//(img)[1]//@src';`

Im getting a blank array though.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="entry">
            <img src="someimagesource.jpg"/>
            <img src="someimagesource123.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Is it the image node itself that you want? Right now, you are querying the attribute `src` of the images. By the way: what is the reason for using `(img)` instead of just `img`?

Comment: I want the first src attribute from the first image on the page.

Comment: Could you include the relevant excerpt of the web page?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll just make one up for you if thats OK?

Comment: Your XPath expression looks OK but just to give it a shot I would make two small changes: try `//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="entry"]//img[1]/@src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to look for first image, here is the xpath:

```
image = '//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="entry"]//img[1]/@src';
```

If you are need the first image (does not need to follow the html structure),

```
DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName
```

is more appropriate. refer here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php